# Is the following a valid countable dense subset of (0,1) the open unit interval?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, alternative-proof, separable-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R} $, $D = \mathbb{Q}$ and $I = (0,1)$. We know that $X$ is a complete metric space and $D$ a countable dense subset, thus making $X$ separable.

First of all, I do know that a subspace of a separable metric space is itself separable. I have learned the proof using second countability, which also gives a construction of said dense subset (I think).

This question however is based on something else:
In this particular case I feel like the first approach one would choose to construct a dense subset would be to just look at $I \cap D$. Now here I would argue that the closure $cl(I \cap D)=[0,1]$ which is not $I$ again, so is $I \cap D$ actually dense in $I$?

Furthermore if this construction works in this particular example, would it be possible to extend this to a proof? Naively translating this would not work, as if $I:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$ the "purely" irrational numbers, then the intersection would just be empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I \cap D$ is indeed dense in $I$ and in general that argument can show that any open subset of a separable (general) space is again separable: the intersection of the dense set with the open set is dense in the open set.

Comment: Right, but would you say that to get to the broader statement (any subset of separable metric space is again separable) would not work with this kind of construction? Also I am curious, since you explicitly said general space here, it is interesting that I didnt use any metric properties, does that extend to the broader statement as well, the proofs I've seen had been strictly on metric spaces i think

Comment: also forgive me for this novice question, but why is $I \cap D$ dense in $I$? I'm working with the definition that the closure has to be $I$ again, but here we get something slightly larger than that?

Comment: @Taleofwoe all that matters is that $I$ lies in that closure. It could be larger. And it’s true in general spaces for open subsets. It needs the metric in more general setting.